# using d3 to draw circles and fill colours dynamically from an array. variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have run this webpage and it says load[x] is not defined in color.js. I couldn't understand why. It looks like simple array which I am accessing through a function.

Details of the code are as follows:

**load.js**

*

```
load=
[
{
"name":"flint",
"x":50,
"y":50,
"s":[
{"t":1},
{"t":3},
{"t":5},
{"t":7},
{"t":9},
{"t":2},
{"t":4},
{"t":6}]
 },
 {
 "name":"oyster",
 "x":100,
"y":100,
 "s":[
{"t":11},
{"t":13},
{"t":15},
{"t":12},
{"t":14},
{"t":16}]
  },
{
"name":"eden",
"x":150,
"y":150,
"s":[
{"t":15},
{"t":30},
{"t":51},
{"t":17},
{"t":29},
{"t":21},
{"t":14}]
    }
   ];
```

*

---

And I am trying to access from an html file inlucding this file under head.
 My **circle.html** code is:

*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="d3.v2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="load.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="color.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",1000).attr("height",1000)
                .selectAll("circle").data(load).enter().append("circle")
                .attr("x",function(d){return d.x;})
                .attr("y",function(d){return d.y;})
                .attr("r",20)
                .attr("fill",function(d,i){return colour(i);});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

*

---

And I am filling the colours by calling a function as follows as specified by **color.js**:

*

```
function colour(k)
 {
 var sum=0,avg;
var i;
for(i=0;i<=load[k].s.length;i++)
{
sum+=load[k].s[i].t;
}
avg=sum/i;
var returncolour;
if(avg<=10){returncolour="#00FF00";}
//else if(avg>10 &avg<=15){returncolour="#0000FF";}
else {returncolour="#FF0000";}
return returncolour;
}
```

*

Comment: It looks like you want `.attr("fill",function(d,i){return colour(i);});` instead of `.attr("fill",function(d){return colour(d);});`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Actually my program was a little bit different. I was using it there. I changed it for simplicity. So now i have added my actual code but it is still with lesser number of data. The colour is still not being filled. Is there any problem with array definition. If yes, why?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: First of All, I wanted to know whether my array load is correct. I want that the colour be filled in circles automatically according to some conditions as mentioned by color.js.The problem is that i am not able to fill the colours in circle (which i will be deploying on maps finally). The error as stated by web console is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 't' of undefined". Help me out!

Comment: Your loop `for(i=0;i<=load[k].s.length;i++)` should be `for(i=0;i<load[k].s.length;i++)`. All of these things are basic Javascript issues. You might want to work your way through a tutorial or two before jumping in at the deep end.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: Thanks, It works. It was silly of me. I didn't noticed. A lot of thanks.